# Jetpack compose visual transformation only number

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

How to implement a visual transformation that it only `digits` and only one `'.'` . This is how I am trying to implement this but getting offset error:

```
class NumberTransformer : VisualTransformation {

override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {

    var out = ""
    var dotCount = text.count { it == '.' }
    text.forEach {
        if (it.isDigit())
            out += it.toString().convertToEnglish()
        if (it == '.' && dotCount == 0)  {
            dotCount++
            out += it
        }
    }

    val numberOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            return offset - dotCount
        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            return offset + dotCount
        }
    }

    return TransformedText(
        text = AnnotatedString(out),
        offsetMapping = numberOffsetTranslator
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is better to use the `onValueChange` parameter to restrict the allowed characters using a regex pattern.

Something like:

```
val pattern = remember { Regex("^\\d*\\.?\\d*\$") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isEmpty() || it.matches(pattern)) {
            text = it
        }
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
)
```

[image]